# Proper way to implement Custom UITableViewCell with TextField Using MvvmCross?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I know this probably isn't the intended way to use UITableViews/MvxTableViewSource/MvxTableViewCell, but I have a unique use case for an iPad only application where users want to edit contents of a TableViewCell within the Cell itself.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXGW1.png)

I've looked through most the Custom TableViewCell examples in the MvvmCross samples GitHub, but I haven't seen any examples that contain any sort of Data Entry within the Cell. Is there an easy way to associate a Cell with a ViewModel? I feel like that would solve my problem. If not, what is the proper way to accomplish this? Thanks.

EDIT: I would like to use a Nib for my custom Cell